# setTimeout is not reset in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I created a hook to be able to set a timeout. Every callback that will be added in that hook will be delayed with a certain amount of time:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const useTimer = () => {
  const timer = useRef();
  const fn = useCallback((callback, timeout = 0) => {
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, timeout);
  }, []);

  const clearTimeoutHandler = () => {
    console.log("clear");
    return clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return clearTimeoutHandler();
  }, []);

  return { fn, clearTimeoutHandler };
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const timer = useTimer();
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setState(true);
    timer.fn(() => {
      console.log(5000);
      setState(false);
    }, 5000);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state && <h1>Hello</h1>}
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Open</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my case `Hello` text will appear after user will click on the button and will disappear after 5000 sec.
 Issue: After clicking 1 time on the button and after 3 sec again clicking on it i expect to see `Hello` text 5 sec right after the last click, but in my case if i click twice the timer will take into account only the first click and if i will click after 3 sec one more time the text will disappear after 2 sec not 5.
 Question: how to fix the hook and to reset the timer if the user click many times or the hook is called many times?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-ride-mlqnri?file=/src/App.js:0-880

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to add `clearTimeout()` to your `useTimer()` function.

Here's your working code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const useTimer = () => {
  const timer = useRef();
  const fn = useCallback((callback, timeout = 0) => {
    // Add this line here
    clearTimeout(timer.current);
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, timeout);
  }, []);

  const clearTimeoutHandler = () => {
    console.log("clear");
    return clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return clearTimeoutHandler();
  }, []);

  return { fn, clearTimeoutHandler };
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const timer = useTimer();
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setState(true);
    timer.fn(() => {
      console.log(5000);
      setState(false);
    }, 5000);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state && <h1>Hello</h1>}
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Open</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And a sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-dream-xmzh9v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i tried to use your example for multiple messages. Expecting to remove one message after one i get removed only the last item from the list. demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-lalande-t0uf7r?file=/src/App.js. . Could you help please and to make the hook workable for both situation? Thanks

Comment: @Asking Here's your working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-hodgkin-5qcjx7?file=/src/App.js . The solution is way simpler than you think: create a different `Timeout` object with each `onClickHandler` call. If the timeout object is different, you don't need to clear it.

Comment: do i understand correct that i don't need to clear the timeout in this case? But why?

Comment: In the first case, the `Timeout` object is the same (`timer.current`) and thus you cannot have multiple timers at the same time. To set another timer, you have to clear the first one. In the second case, each time `onClickHandler` is called, a new timer is created, and thus you don't need to clear the previous timeout to start a new one Is it clearer now?.

Comment: But the timeout should be cleared after the component is unmounted or not in the last case? And is there a way to modify the hook to make it workable for both situations?

Comment: i wanted to say that if i will have a button that will be responsible to remove all messages like `updateList([])`, then in this case should i remove the timeout or not? Also i thought about a reusable hook if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the ref directly to clearTimeout

```js
 const clearTimeoutHandler = () => {
    console.log("clear");
    return clearTimeout(timer); // should be timer.current
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clear previous timer in `fn` function, and assign null to `timer.current` after callback function is invoke.
this is my code below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-fire-jgujww?file=/src/App.js:0-977

Comment: In addition to linking to a demo, make sure to paste the actual code in your answer. This preserves against link rot over time and makes sure that other users can quickly assess your answer and see if it works for their problems.